# Ejecutar función de componente padre desde componente hijo, dinámicamente de acuerdo a variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Quisiera ejecutar una función de mi componente padre desde el componente hijo, de forma dinámica. Cuento con una variable donde tengo el nombre de la función que deseo ejecutar.

He tratado de la siguiente forma pero no lo consigo.

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<template id="child-template">
    <span @click="someMethod">Click me!</span>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <child></child>
</div>

<script>
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '#child-template',
  data: function () {
      return {
        modulo: 'msj1',
      }
  },
  methods: {
    someMethod(){
        this.$parent.(this.modulo);
    }
    }
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  methods: {
    msj1(){
        alert('mensaje 1');
    },
    msj2(){
        alert('mensaje 2');
    },
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo debes ajustar la llamada a la funcion (usando `[]` para acceder al metodo por nombre y `()` para efectuar la llamada):

```
this.$parent[this.modulo]();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<template id="child-template">
    <span @click="someMethod">Click me!</span>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <child></child>
</div>

<script>
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '#child-template',
  data: function () {
      return {
        modulo: 'msj1',
      }
  },
  methods: {
    someMethod(){
        this.$parent[this.modulo]();
    }
    }
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  methods: {
    msj1(){
        alert('mensaje 1');
    },
    msj2(){
        alert('mensaje 2');
    },
    }
});
</script>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Parent-Component-Instance